# why two pointer of same struct which only used new function for creating compares equal in go

Tags: go

I want to compare 2 instance of the same struct to find out if it is equal, and got two different result.

1. comment the code // fmt.Println("%#v\n", a), the program output is "Equal"
2. Use the fmt to print variable "a", then I got the output "Not Equal"

Please help me to find out Why???

I use golang 1.2.1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type example struct {
}

func init() {
   _ = fmt.Printf
}

func main() {

    a := new(example)
    b := new(example)

    // fmt.Println("%#v\n", a)
    if a == b { 
        println("Equals")
    } else {
        println("Not Equals")
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several aspects involved here:

1. You generally cannot compare the value of a struct by comparing the pointers: `a` and `b` are pointers to `example` not instances of example. `a==b` compares the pointers (i.e. the memory address) not the values.
2. Unfortunately your `example` is the empty struct `struct{}` and everything is different for the one and only empty struct in the sense that it does not really exist as it occupies no space and thus all different `struct {}` may (or may not) have the same address.

All this has nothing to do with calling fmt.Println. The special behavior of the empty struct just manifests itself through the reflection done by fmt.Println.

Just do not use `struct {}` to test how any real struct would behave.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the correct answer, as can be seen using `go objdump` – the empty struct is not real, and usually compares equal to itself. Using Println forces `a` to become something real, after which the equality no longer holds.

Comment: I downvoted it before I realized that his answer was correct. Then I tried to change the vote to an upvote but StackOverflow tells me "Your vote is locked until this answer is edited". So that's why.